# RxSwift - How to throttle buffer's time span

Tags: swift, rxjs, rx-swift, reactivex

I am trying to recreate a code snippet that basically counts how many times a button was clicked in a row. The code is in RxJS and I am trying to convert it to RxSwift for learning purposes but can't figure out the buffer and throttle part.

[You can see the js code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/4gGgs/27/)

Currently I have this

```
  tapButton.rx.tap      
  .buffer(timeSpan: 0.25, count: 10, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
  .map {$0.count}
  .filter { $0 >= 2 }
  .subscribe(onNext: { events in
    print(events)
  }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

And I can't figure out how can I delay until tapping ends and collect all values since the last emission like in the RxJS example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is because the RxSwift `buffer` operator doesn't work like the RxJS `buffer` operator. It works more like the RxJS `bufferWithTimeOrCount` operator.

Currently, as of version 3.4.0, there is no equivalent to the `buffer` operator. It's signature would be something like `func buffer(_ boundary: Observer<BoundaryType>) -> Observable<[E]>`

This has been a fun question to answer. I ended up making a buffer operator which I provide at the bottom of this answer. Here is how I would write the solution out that is defined in Andre's code:

```
    let trigger = button.rx.tap.debounce(0.25, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    let clickStream = button.rx.tap.asObservable()
        .buffer(trigger)
        .map { $0.count }
        .map { $0 == 1 ? "click" : "\($0)x clicks" }

    let clearStream = clickStream
        .debounce(10.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .map { _ in "" }

    Observable.merge([clickStream, clearStream])
        .bind(to: label.rx.text)
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

The above code should be placed in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. There is one big change and one small change that I made. The small change is that I used debounce instead of throttle. Again, I think RxJS's throttle works differently than RxSwift's throttle does. The big change is that I combined his multiClickStream and singleClickStream. I'm not entirely sure why he made two separate streams...

Another change I made was to roll all the observables that affect the label into one observable that the label could bind to, instead of having different ones. I think this is cleaner.

Below is the buffer operator that I defined.

```
extension Observable {

    /// collects elements from the source sequence until the boundary sequence fires. Then it emits the elements as an array and begins collecting again.
    func buffer<U>(_ boundary: Observable<U>) -> Observable<[E]> {
        return Observable<[E]>.create { observer in
            var buffer: [E] = []
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            let boundaryDisposable = boundary.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .next:
                    observer.onNext(buffer)
                    buffer = []
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            let disposable = self.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .next(let element):
                    buffer.append(element)
                case .completed:
                    observer.onNext(buffer)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                    buffer = []
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create([disposable, boundaryDisposable])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will let the question hang a little bit more in case someone comes with a solution or I myself figure something out.

Comment: You might find this discussion interesting: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/590

Comment: Thank you very much for both the solution and the explanation. 