# Swift Combine Chunk Operator

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to create chunks of a stream in Apple's Combine framework.

What I'm going for is something like this:

```
Stream a:
--1-2-3-----4-5--->

Stream b:
--------0-------0->

a.chunk(whenOutputFrom: b)

-------[1, 2, 3]---[4, 5]-->
```

Can this be implemented in Combine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`buffer`](https://rxmarbles.com/#buffer) operator in the ReactiveX world.

There is no built in `buffer` operator (in the ReactiveX sense) in Combine. The built-in `buffer` is seems to be more like a `bufferCount` in ReactiveX.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413167/5133585) by Daniel T, which recreates the `buffer` operator in RxSwift, and also [this cheatsheet](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/rxswift-to-combine-cheatsheet), which tells you how to port RxSwift to Combine.

However, the answer by Daniel T uses `Observable.create`, which isn't available in Combine. I looked a bit deeper, and found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035663/5133585), that recreates `Observable.create` in Combine.

Combining the three things I've found (no pun intended), this is what I came up with:

```
// -------------------------------------------------
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035663/5133585
struct AnyObserver<Output, Failure: Error> {
    let onNext: ((Output) -> Void)
    let onError: ((Failure) -> Void)
    let onCompleted: (() -> Void)
}

struct Disposable {
    let dispose: () -> Void
}

extension AnyPublisher {
    static func create(subscribe: @escaping (AnyObserver<Output, Failure>) -> Disposable) -> Self {
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
        var disposable: Disposable?
        return subject
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { subscription in
                disposable = subscribe(AnyObserver(
                    onNext: { output in subject.send(output) },
                    onError: { failure in subject.send(completion: .failure(failure)) },
                    onCompleted: { subject.send(completion: .finished) }
                ))
            }, receiveCancel: { disposable?.dispose() })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------  

// -------------------------------------------------
// adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413167/5133585
extension Publisher {

    /// collects elements from the source sequence until the boundary sequence fires. Then it emits the elements as an array and begins collecting again.
    func buffer<T: Publisher, U>(_ boundary: T) -> AnyPublisher<[Output], Failure> where T.Output == U {
        return AnyPublisher.create { observer in
            var buffer: [Output] = []
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            let boundaryDisposable = boundary.sink(receiveCompletion: {
                _ in
            }, receiveValue: {_ in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                observer.onNext(buffer)
                buffer = []
            })
            let disposable = self.sink(receiveCompletion: { (event) in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .finished:
                    observer.onNext(buffer)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .failure(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                    buffer = []
                }
            }) { (element) in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                buffer.append(element)
            }
            return Disposable {
                disposable.cancel()
                boundaryDisposable.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This worked for me. I created a version that doesn't need the additional types and `create` function: https://gist.github.com/xavierLowmiller/e9cbd460a4f8ef4cf16cfa4e181c9351

Answer (score 3):

I think you would be interested in Combine [collect()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/buffer/3235939-collect) method.
there is variation it it as well such as by time, count or both.

```swift
.collect(.byTimeOrCount(DispatchQueue.global(), 1.0, 10))
```

where we pass context -> for example global queue
time to wait for it such as 1s in above example
and the count of 10 elements.

Use case would look something like this:

```swift
let bufferSubject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let cancelBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let subscriber = bufferSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  .collect(.byTimeOrCount(DispatchQueue.global(), 1.0, 10))
  .sink { value in
      print(" value: \(value)")
  }
  .store(in: &cancelBag)
```

be sure to test it :)

```swift
bufferSubject.send(1)
bufferSubject.send(2)
bufferSubject.send(3)

...

DispatchQueue.asyncAfter(...) {
  bufferSubject.send(4)
  bufferSubject.send(5)
  bufferSubject.send(6)
}
```